# Appcelerator Titanium - Opening a website within a mobile app

Tags: javascript, window, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I'm trying to open a website on a button click from my app. Its just a simple help button that should open the site's help page. Nothing too fancy. But I'm having a lot of trouble getting it to load.

Here is my code relating to this:

```
var helpButton = $.help;
var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView(URL_HELP);
helpButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    try {
        var helpWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow();
        helpWin.add(webview);
        helpWin.open({modal:true});
    } catch (e) {
        Ti.API.error("Error: " + e);
    }
});
```

The error is never getting caught as well. On the button click, it loads a new window, but is left loading perpetually. I'm not sure what the problem is, or where to go from here.

Please help, and let me know if you have any other questions or ideas.

Comment: Did you get any logs/warnings at all? What does URL_HELP looks like?

Comment: No warnings given, nothing logged. Just gets stalled opening the page. URL_HELP is just a link to the help page for the company. Its defined in another class, but I've checked, and the URL is defined correctly.

Comment: Will be truly hard to diagnose without a runnable test case. You may want to submit a report to the team to dig into this further. http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/How_to_Submit_a_Bug_Report

Comment: `var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView(URL_HELP);`  or  `var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({url : URL_HELP});`.

Comment: Is there a problem with that line of code? As shown in the question, I have that line in there already. Its the second line in the block.

Answer (score 0):

first of all try to create webview having it's properties set to required values.following code is working fine for me.

```
var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
    url: 'http://stackoverflow.com/tour',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%"
});
```

you can try this with your url.

**Note:** instead of creating webview global to this file you can create it after create window in help button click event if you only want to show help page. so you code should look something like this. you can also use $.help.addEventListener instead of assigning it to a separate variable.

```
$.help.addEventListener('click', function() {
    try {
        var helpWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow();
        var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
            url: URL_HELP,
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%"
        });
        helpWin.add(webview);
        helpWin.open({modal:true});
    } catch (e) {
        Ti.API.error("Error: " + e);
    }
});
```